# Service-Side jQuery Mobile on Phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

We have a jQueryMobile application where each page is dynamically served from an application server. We don't do any AJAX or JSON ourselves but rely on JQM to fetch the html pages which are served.

Is it possible to wrap application as an App using PhoneGap?

**Background:**

As I understand it PhoneGap expects you to package all your html+js+css locally. In theory my application could have one static .htm start page inside the PhoneGap app but the very next click (say "Login") would be to http://myserver.com/.

Isn't PhoneGap gonna block that?

Will Apple reject the app because it's just a wrapper for the browser?

In short, do I have to make a fully AJAX+JSON application in order to use PhoneGap if I want server communication?

Answer (score 0):

The *App Stores Review Guidelines* on the section *2.Functionality* states that:

> Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected.

So in case that you follow the approach of fetching server side HTML pages then most probably your app will be rejected.

Comment: This is as I suspected. However if HTML is code then the FaceBook apps (and many others which display 3rd party sites) are illegal.